# How to Enable Sticky Sessions in tomcat loadbalancer?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, load-balancing, mod-jk

My task is to loadbalance web traffic among **Apache Tomcat** server instances via **mod_jk**.

I already have configured the **load-balancing**, but It does not keep the same session for same request, it redirects to another Tomcat server instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your workers.properties set the sticky_session option to 1:

```
worker.list=balancer,lbstats

#node1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.host=127.0.0.1
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.lbfactor=10

#node2
...

#lb config
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.sticky_session=1

worker.balancer.balance_workers=node1,node2

#lb status information (optional)
worker.lbstats.type=status
```

**Update**

One reason could be that the session gets lost during requests. Make sure you did set the jvmRoute attribute in the engine element in server.xml:

```
<Engine jvmRoute="node1" defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
```

The name must match the nodes name from workers.properites (see above). This name will be appended to your session ids. Make sure it does not change during requests.

Furthermore define a status worker as shown above, and map it to a url in your httpd.conf file:

```
JkMount /modjkstatus    lbstats
```

After that access http://yourdomain.xyz/modjkstatus to see further cluster and lb information.

Comment: Hello Stefan, I have set the value of "worker.balancer.sticky_session" to 1 , but still not working. any oather method?

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thank you for the update, I did all the things that u hv mentioned, but if I added this line <Engine jvmRoute="node1" defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina"> , the tomcat server instance is not started. If I commented that one, the instance is started. Any idea about this?

Comment: The line already exists in you Tomcats server.xml. You only need to add the jvmRoute="NAME" attribute.